# How to refresh a parent form after a plugin is executed on a child window?

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, refresh, parent

I have a plugin that updates a value in the Contact Form after an Email has been created.

I need to refresh the Contact form after this plugin runs without having to close and reopen the form to see the update. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a plugin to force a refresh in a client window.  Plugins run on the server, and don't have a way to communicate directly with the client that caused the update.

But, if you have some sort of Ribbon button on the Contact form that creates the e-mail, you could refresh the page from the javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I create the email by using the ribbon button "Create New Activity"--> Email. To which even should I add such a script ?

Comment: @user3340627 You're using the button to open up a new form.  It's not actually creating it.

Comment: Yes, so there is no way to force a refresh to the Contact form when I close the Email form ?

Comment: You should be able to do something about it via js using the OnSave event on the email form, be careful the script will run every time you will try to save an email message. Try to use window.parent.document to retrieve the contact window where you pressed the ribbon "create new activity" button.